# mariaDBで日本語入力ができない

Tags: mysql, aws, sql, database, mariadb

marinaDBで日本語を入力しようとすると、文字を打ててもエンターを押すと消えてしまいます。
環境は
AWSのクラウド9
Amazon Linux2
EC2はt2.micro
networkのセッティングはSSH
mariaDBのversionは10.2
です。

環境変数は
LANG=ja_JA.UTF-8
LC_ALL=ja_JA.UTF-8
としましたし、mariaDBの文字コードもutf8mb4に設定したのですが直りません。[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]
情報のある方いらっしゃいましたらご教授ください。

Comment: 関係あるかわかりませんが、とりあえず ja_JA は ja_JP の誤りじゃないですかね？「言語名_国名」という表記なので

Comment: おっしゃる通りでした。ただ、直してみてもまだ日本語入力ができません。ご指摘いただきありがとうございました。